# html5: Using the dl element to associate a person with its academic titles – appropriate usage?

Tags: html, semantics

When marking up a person's name together with academic titles this person has achieved, is it appropriate to use a `<dl>`? Like so:

```
<dl>
    <dt>John Doe</dt>
    <dd>Doctor of Physical Therapy</dd>
    <dd>Doctor of Pharmacy</dd>
</dl>
```

From the [html5 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/single-page.html#the-dl-element):

> The dl element represents an association list consisting of zero or more name-value groups (a description list).
>   […]
>   Name-value groups may be terms and definitions, metadata topics and values, questions and answers, or any other groups of name-value data.

They also give this example which seems a bit similar:

```
<dl>
    <dt> Authors
    <dd> John
    <dd> Luke
    <dt> Editor
    <dd> Frank
</dl>
```

At the same time they state

> The values within a group are alternatives; multiple paragraphs forming part of the same value must all be given within the same dd element.

Which is something I don't quite get, that's why I am asking here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are trying to express a list of people and what they *are*, `dl` seems appropriate.

```
<dl>
    <dt>John Doe</dt>
    <dd>Doctor of Physical Therapy</dd>
    <dd>Doctor of Pharmacy</dd>
</dl>
```

This says to me that John Doe *is* a Doctor of Physical Therapy and of Pharmacy (in no particular order). Very much in the spirit of a dictionary; you list a *term* (`dt`) and its *definition(s)* (`dd`). I'd expect there to be more entries in this *list* (`dl`), and it should also be *styled* in terms of such a list of definitions.

If that's not your intention, a micro format hCard might be more what you're after. See http://microformats.org/wiki/hcard.